# For publishers having books priced less than $10, calculate the average price of all their books

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Someone please help, it's really annoying me that I cannot figure it out.
I know how to do `avg` and how to find out publishers having books under 10 but how to define the criterion?
Please see the schema below,

```
TITLES
title_id
title
type
price
pub_id
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TITLES, title_id, title, type, price, pub_id

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select pub_id, avg(price)
from TITLES
group by pub_id
having min(price) < 10
```